# How to render a specific character as transparent in terminal

Tags: terminal, iterm, tmux

I'm looking for a way of rendering a single character / escape sequence as transparent in iTerm2 or, if there is one, any other terminal emulator. With transparent I mean that it should show the background behind the window rendering the terminal.

The reason behind this is a purely astethic one: I'd like to use this special character with tmux to render the split views so that my panes are separated by, frankly, my wallpaper. Using tmux for panes seems so much more flexible than using a (tiling) window manager for opening multiple terminals - but one of the asthetic drawbacks is that I cannot have a gap between the panes.

While I'm pretty much certain that there is no easy answer to that, I'm also very open to hear any pointers into a direction where a certain terminal application could be modified to support such a behavior in an easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like iTerm supports this -- here are their proprietary escape sequences:

https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html

It seems like a great feature to add, if you're a programmer looking to contribute to iTerm2! Their github repo is here:

https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2